# Can an HDMI signal go from laptop through a splitter ?

Tags: hdmi

I have following question. 
I have 1 HDMI output on laptop and I need to pass HDMI signal both to TV and to Home Cinema receiver 
 
Question: Is it enough to use HDMI Splitter like  [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FMJLQC) ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd recommend restructuring your question to not be a buying recommendation, which how this can be construed (see the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq)).  Should be pretty easy, just something like "Can an HDMI signal go through a splitter without quality degradation?" or something, otherwise - this will likely be closed.  BTW - Welcome to SU!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly encourage using an Active HDMI splitter. You might be able to find one that does it passively, but the signal could be badly degraded and it would likely be less reliable then spending $30 - $50 on a decent active splitter.

What you linked to might work, but it is far from ideal. Also the rating for that item is 1.5 stars... not good.

Answer (score 0):

Active or you wouldn't have enough power to run the signal. powered splitter not a passive splitter